# Cannot connect into web camera using opencv

Tags: python, opencv

I have a program that is a face recognition application and I want to run it on a PC client.

But it shows an error like this
[image]

I think it might be that the program cannot connect to any camera device in my client ,

in my python code i use this

```
cap=cv2.VideoCapture(0)
```

and i have install logitech camera driver in my client pc

[image]

but it is still can not detect any camera in my client

how can i solve this?

Answer (score 0):

I've had this issue before and what solved it for me was using a different USB port on the PC for the webcam. It was due to the driver being connected to certain ports that opencv read from.